# AVCaptureStillImageOutput Output Image Dimensions

Tags: ios, objective-c, avcapturesession

I am trying to find a way to get the dimensions (width and height) of an AVCaptureStillImageOutput's output image as soon as I create it.

Most examples I've found on the web retrieve this information when the user snaps their first photo, but I would like to initialize this info when I am setting up my AVCaptureSession.

Preferably, it would be nice to get the info after creating the AVCaptureStillImageOutput and adding it as an output to my AVCaptureSession.

The dimensions for an AVCaptureVideoDataOutput can be retrieved like so:

```
AVCaptureVideoDataOutput* dataOutput = [[AVCaptureVideoDataOutput alloc] init];

[myAVCaptureSession addOutput:dataOutput];

NSDictionary* videoSettings = dataOutput.videoSettings;

NSNumber* displayWidth = [videoSettings objectForKey:@"Width"];
if (displayWidth != nil)
{
    self.displayWidth = [displayWidth intValue];
}

NSNumber* displayHeight = [videoSettings objectForKey:@"Height"];
if (displayHeight != nil)
{
    self.displayHeight = [displayHeight intValue];
}
```

I would like to do something similar, but with AVCaptureStillImageOutput. Unfortunately, I haven't been able to find a way.

Thanks!